# Importing modules with no relative path using webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, pixi.js

I am developing a web game that I want to package with webpack. At the same time I am building multiple library npm packages for future games. The dependency tree looks something like this

```
Game
    |__ Lib1
        |__ Lib2
                |__PIXI.Js
```

The libs are inside the Game node_modules folder

So the game is dependent on my Lib1 npm package, which is dependent on my Lib2 npm package which is dependent on the third party library PIXI.js.
My game application will contain the webpack config file to bring all this together. One of the classes inside Lib2 is a RenderWindow class for setting up PIXI.js and imports PIXI like this:

```
import * as PIXI from 'PIXI'
```

Usually the last part of the above line contains a relative path to where PIXI can be found but it is useful for library developers to effectively rely on it being loaded externally so it isnt bundled together. My understanding is that you set this up with externals in webpack config like so:

```
externals: {
    PIXI: 'PIXI',
  }
```

In order to tie all this together pixi needs to be loaded and exposed as part of the global window object which is where expose-loader comes in to webpack:

```
test: require.resolve("./node_modules/lib2node_modules/pixi.js/dist/browser/pixi.js"),
            use: [{
                loader: 'expose-loader',
                options: {
                    exposes: "PIXI"
                }
            }]
        }
```

Now wherever I want to use PIXI in either Lib1 or Lib2 or my game I should just be able to import it like this:

```
import * as PIXI from 'PIXI'
```

However it doesnt seem to work, and gives the following error when I run webpack

```
Cannot find module 'PIXI' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

The following is the full output of the webpack command:

```
> typescript_test@0.0.1 standalone__debug
> webpack --mode development --env engine=standalone && webpack-dev-server --open --mode development --env engine=standalone

asset vendor.js 1.68 MiB [compared for emit] [minimized] (name: vendor) 1 related asset
  asset lib2.js 1.74 KiB [emitted] [minimized] (name: lib2) 1 related asset
  asset game.js 282 bytes [compared for emit] [minimized] (name: game)     1 related asset
asset index.html 136 bytes [compared for emit]
asset changelog.txt 0 bytes [compared for emit] [from:    changelog.txt] [copied]
runtime modules 3.53 KiB 7 modules
built modules 1.63 MiB [built]
  modules by path ../lib2/ 1.63 MiB
    modules by path ../lib2/node_modules/pixi.js/dist/browser/*.js 1.63 MiB
      ../lib2/node_modules/pixi.js/dist/browser/pixi-exposed.js 608 bytes [built] [code generated]
      ../lib2/node_modules/pixi.js/dist/browser/pixi.js 1.63 MiB [built] [code generated]
    modules by path ../lib2/src/*.ts 397 bytes
      ../lib2/src/index.ts 150 bytes [built] [code generated]
  ../lib2/src/RenderWindow.ts 247 bytes [built] [code generated] [1 error]
  modules by path ./ 713 bytes
    ./src/standalone.ts 14 bytes [built] [code generated]
./node_modules/expose-loader/dist/runtime/getGlobalThis.js 699 bytes [built] [code generated]
  external "PIXI" 42 bytes [built] [code generated]

ERROR in /lib2/src/RenderWindow.ts
../lib2/src/RenderWindow.ts 2:22-28
[tsl] ERROR in /lib2/src/RenderWindow.ts(2,23)
  TS2307: Cannot find module 'PIXI' or its corresponding type declarations.
ts-loader-default_e3b0c44298fc1c14
 @ ../lib2/src/index.ts 3:0-47 4:0-6:15

webpack 5.70.0 compiled with 1 error in 2202 ms
```

The file that it is erroring with is the RenderWindow.ts which simply looks like this and it is complaining about the import

```
'use strict';
import * as PIXI from 'PIXI'

export class RenderWindow{
private app: PIXI.Application;
public constructor(){
    this.app = new PIXI.Application({ width: 400, height: 400, backgroundColor: 0xFFFFFF });
    document.body.appendChild(this.app.view);
}
}
```

Comment: `Now wherever I want to use PIXI in either Lib1 or Lib2 or my game I should just be able to import it like this: import * as PIXI from 'PIXI'` - if understand correctly there might be multiple folders at "Lib1" level, and inside each such folder there might me multiple "Lib2" libraries (each with own dependencies)? In that case its strange that something at "Lib1" level will depend on something from "Lib2" level (for example on PIXI). Are you sure this is correct hierarchy?

Comment: One more note: you should design structure of your project in such way where PixiJS library is added only once. Duplicate Pixi packages in one project (or multiple versions of it) is common mistake. Please search for similar problems in https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/discussions/ and https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/issues - and if you dont find answer please post new discussion. Would be best if you can provide example minimal repo which demonstrates your problem (with directory structure, webpack config etc).

Comment: What I was trying to achieve is Lib2 pulls in Pixi and Lib2 has many usable classes designed for all web based games. Like initialsing the renderer, player input etc. Generic game stuff. Lib1 is more a specific type of game lib, like a FPS. It depends on Lib2 because it wants to make use of the generic game code. It gets access to PIXI through Lib2 which is dependent on PIXI. Lib0 could be say an RPG lib which is also dependent on Lib2 (but not lib1). The game would then be dependent on lib1 or lib2 depending on its game type, and will also get access to PIXI through the dependency tree.Thanks